# Laravel Progressive Image using Image intervention

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, progressive-web-apps

I want to know how to apply progressive image in my website.
I'm using Image intervention. I search some way to apply image intervention
but I did not understand. Like

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.png');
$img->interlace();
```

the original image and image that interlace don't have difference.
Can anyone help me to understand progressive image and how to apply it using image itervention in my website?

Comment: It's just a difference in how they load over network. once the image is loaded, there'll be no difference between interlaced and non-interlaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in this illustration:

[image: An illustration of interlacing over a 16×16 image]

> **Interlacing (also known as interleaving)** is a method of encoding a bitmap image such that a person who has partially received it sees a degraded copy of the entire image.
>
> ...
>
> For example: Interlaced GIF is a GIF image that seems to arrive on your display like an image coming through a slowly opening Venetian blind. A fuzzy outline of an image is gradually replaced by seven successive waves of bit streams that fill in the missing lines until the image arrives at its full resolution.
>
> ~ [*Interlacing (bitmaps) on Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps))

In another word, you won't see any visual difference between two images unless you try to load them with a low-speed connection within a modern web browser.
(See: [Firefox DevTools has now a network throttling tool to simulate slow connections](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/11/07/simulate-slow-connections-with-the-network-throttling-tool/))

---

And BTW, your code was [correct](http://image.intervention.io/api/interlace). I guess you were just trying to see a difference between interlaced and non-interlaced images which you will not be able to as long as they are not huge and they'll load fast.

---

For better understanding:

- [Videos of SCTP vs TCP in ***progressive*** vs ***non-progressive***](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Eleighton/firefox.html)